# How to pass data out from a method

Tags: variables, layout, methods

I have a problem with a part of code in my Android application. I need to get the text saved in the `tmp` variable to see if it is `null` or not, but I'm not able to get the information from method `onGlobalLayout`. How can I do this? I'm not an expert, so I wish you could help me.

```
public void setText (){
    int i = 0;
    tmp = stringResponse;
    //Log.i("TMP", " 1 " + tmp);
    final PageTurnLayout flipper = (PageTurnLayout) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    while (i != 15){
        final TextView tv = new TextView (this);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setPadding(7, 5, 5, 0);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                tv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                tv.setText(tmp);
                tmp = getInvisibleText(tv);
                tmp2 = getVisibleText(tv);

                tv.setText(tmp2);
            }});

        flipper.addView(tv);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `tmp` isn't declared anywhere in the code shown, and you haven't specified WHERE in your code you need to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tmp holds a string, try changing public void setText() to public String setText(), and at the bottom of the function use return(tmp);
Also, when you call the function, you will have to have a String variable(Ex. tmptext), and call the function by saying tmptext = setText();
This will return the value of tmp into the value of tmptext, and you can then use that value. I'm not sure why you have a function inside another, but you could (probably) have them separate, and just use recursion to call the functions.

Sorry if I missunderstood, it's been a while since I've done anything in Java.